# How to reverse the order of SortedSet

Tags: java, treeset, sortedset

I want to print an ordered list in Map using the following:

```
Map<Float, String> mylist = new HashMap<>();

mylist.put(10.5, a);
mylist.put(12.3, b);
mylist.put(5.1, c);

SortedSet<Float> orderlist = new TreeSet<Float>(mylist.keySet());

for (Float i : orderlist) {
    System.out.println(i+" "+mylist.get(i));
}
```

The above code prints:

```
5.1 c
10.5 a
12.3 b
```

But how do I the print the orderlist in reverse order like below:

```
12.3 b
10.5 a
5.1 c
```

Comment: Are you against placing the items from the set in another data structure? Additionally, are you required to have the items in the `SortedSet` in the specific order they're already in, or would you be okay with storing them in reverse order?

Comment: I just want to print the list. There is no requirement to SortedSet if there is a better way. It is ok if I can store items in reverse order.

Answer (score 13):

If you're willing to store the elements in the `SortedSet` in reverse order, the only change you need to make is to construct the `TreeSet` with [an appropriate constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)) which takes a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Map<Float, String> mylist = new HashMap<>();

mylist.put(10.5, a);
mylist.put(12.3, b);
mylist.put(5.1, c);

SortedSet<Float> orderlist = new TreeSet<Float>(Collections.reverseOrder());
orderList.addAll(mylist.keySet());

for (Float i : orderlist) {
    System.out.println(i+" "+mylist.get(i));
}
```

Note the neat method here is [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder()) which returns a `Comparator` which compares in the opposite of the natural ordering of elements.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome!

Comment: No problem! [SO etiquette for a thank-you is an upvote and a "mark as answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this :

```
    Map<Float, String> mylist = new HashMap<Float, String>();
    mylist.put(10.5, a);
    mylist.put(12.3, b);
    mylist.put(5.1, c);

    SortedSet<Float> orderlist = new TreeSet<Float>(mylist.keySet()).descendingSet();

    for (Float i : orderlist) {
        System.out.println(i+" "+mylist.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `NavigableSet`:

```
 public NavigableSet<E> descendingSet()
```

Like this:

```
  SortedSet<Float> orderlist = new TreeSet<Float>(mylist.keySet());
  SortedSet<Float> treereverse = new TreeSet<Float>();
  // creating reverse set
  treereverse=(TreeSet)orderlist.descendingSet();
```

Finally you have `treereverse` with the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this implementation ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853085/3764804)):

```
public sealed class OrderedSet<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>> _dictionary;
    private readonly LinkedList<T> _linkedList;

    public OrderedSet()
        : this(EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    private OrderedSet(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<T, LinkedListNode<T>>(comparer);
        _linkedList = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public int Count => _dictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => _dictionary.IsReadOnly;

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _linkedList.Clear();
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        var found = _dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out var node);
        if (!found)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _dictionary.Remove(item);
        _linkedList.Remove(node);
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _linkedList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _linkedList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            return;
        }

        var node = _linkedList.AddLast(item);
        _dictionary.Add(item, node);
    }

    public void Reverse()
    {
        var head = _linkedList.First;
        while (head.Next != null)
        {
            var next = head.Next;
            _linkedList.Remove(next);
            _linkedList.AddFirst(next.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is an `OrderSet` which preserves the insertion order unlike [`SortedSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8) which keeps the set sorted according to some comparator (e.g. alphabetically).

I added the `Reverse()` method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571033/3764804).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 21, the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html#reversed()) method can be used to return a reversed view on the set, which can then be iterated over using an enhanced `for` statement:

```java
for (Float i : orderlist) {
    System.out.println(i+" "+mylist.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a `SortedSet` for just the keys and looking up the value for each key, you can use a `SortedMap` and iterate over the map's entries.  The map can be sorted in reversed order using the [`Comparator.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()) comparator.

```java
Map<Float, String> mylist = new HashMap<>();

mylist.put(10.5, a);
mylist.put(12.3, b);
mylist.put(5.1, c);

SortedMap<Float, String> orderlist = new TreeMap<Float>(Comparator.reversed());
orderlist.putAll(mylist);

for (Map.Entry<Float, String> e : orderlist.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}
```

If you aren't using `mylist` as a `HashMap` separately from this iteration, the `SortedMap` can be used directly.

```java
SortedMap<Float, String> mylist = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reversed());

mylist.put(10.5, a);
mylist.put(12.3, b);
mylist.put(5.1, c);

for (Map.Entry<Float, String> e : mylist.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}
```